# Cassandra shows three dots when i run any query

Tags: cassandra

it is the first time i use cassandra, so please excuse me if my question is naive :)
I have downloaded and extracted cassandra 1.2.4
i have run it using `/usr/local/apache-cassandra-1.2.4/bin/cassandra -f`
now i connect to it

```
root@Alaa:/usr/local/apache-cassandra-1.2.4# ./bin/cassandra-cli
Connected to: "Test Cluster" on 127.0.0.1/9160
Welcome to Cassandra CLI version 1.2.4

Type 'help;' or '?' for help.
Type 'quit;' or 'exit;' to quit.

[default@unknown] show cluster name
...
```

and those three dots remain forever!! any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to terminate the command with a `;`, otherwise the shell has no way of telling that you're "done" entering a query/command:

```
show cluster name;
                 ^---
```

That's why the `help;`, `quit;`, and `exit;` examples printed as part of the startup all include a `;`...

Comment: Thanks a lot :) i was reading and applying exactly what have been written in "Cassandra the definitive guide" and they didn't list the semicolon!! i dont know why :)

Comment: "The definitive guide" is so out of date as to be useless.  You can find up-to-date documentation at http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/index

Comment: It is also possible that you have a syntax error in your query. If you: INSERT INTO Table1(col1, col2) VALUES ('string', 'string); This will still give you a ... because string for col2 is missing a closing single quote on the end.